# How to parse particular JSON file in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, json, swift, swiftui

Let's say I'm trying to parse this particular JSON file with SwiftUI:

***data.json***

```
[
    {
        "number": 1,
        "word": "hello",
        "sentence": {
            "word_one": "my",
            "word_two": "name"
            "word_three": "is"
            "word_four": "jeff"
        }
    },
    {
        "number": 2,
        "word": "there",
        "sentence": {
            "word_one": "i",
            "word_two": "dream"
            "word_three": "about"
            "word_four": "cheese"
        }
    }
]
```

I understand how to parse `number` and `word`, but what I'm having trouble with is how to parse everything in `sentence`. I am new to iOS programming and the resources I've been looking at are confusing to me. This is the code I have thus far:

```
struct Content: Codable, Hashable {
    let number: Int
    let word: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    func jsonParse() -> [Content] {
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "json")!
            let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let products = try? decoder.decode([Content].self, from: data)
            return products!
        }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(jsonParse(), id: \.self) { content in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                        Text("\(content.word)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your JSON data contains two dictionaries, which are not number and word.

Comment: @ElTomato Is there something I'm doing wrong with my struct?

Comment: You could declare `sentence` as a dictionary `[String:String]`

Comment: @Paulw11 How would I then create text with ```sentence``` on the ```ContentView```? Would it be something like  ```Text("\(content.sentence.word_one)")```?

Comment: No, You will need to get the `keys` of the dictionary and sort the array and then iterate over the sorted array for keys and access the value `for key in dictionary.keys.sorted { Text(dictionary[key])` kind of thing; I would put the keys and sorting behind a computed variable in your model and use `ForEach`

Comment: Your JSON data is invalid.

Comment: @ElTomato How should I go about changing it?

Answer (score 1):

First, your JSON data is invalid.  It should be the following.

```
[
    {
        "number": 1,
        "word": "hello",
        "sentence": {
            "word_one": "my",
            "word_two": "name",
            "word_three": "is",
            "word_four": "jeff"
        }
    },
    {
        "number": 2,
        "word": "there",
        "sentence": {
            "word_one": "i",
            "word_two": "dream",
            "word_three": "about",
            "word_four": "cheese"
        }
    }
]
```

No. 2, read your data as follows.

```
import UIKit

struct Content: Decodable {
    let number: Int
    let word: String
    let sentence: Sentence
}

struct Sentence: Decodable {
    let word_one: String
    let word_two: String
    let word_three: String
    let word_four: String
}
```

Finally, read your JSON file in the bundle as follows.

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "jsonData14", ofType: "json") {
   if let jsonData = readFileContent(path: path) {
      do {
         let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Content].self, from: jsonData)
         print(result)
         
         } catch let error as NSError {
         print("\(error)")
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi as El Tomato pointed out your JSON is invalid. I used the fixed JSON that was provided from El Tomato.

If you simply want the answer here it is.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let json = """
[
    {
        "number": 1,
        "word": "hello",
        "sentence": {
            "word_one": "my",
            "word_two": "name",
            "word_three": "is",
            "word_four": "jeff"
        }
    },
    {
        "number": 2,
        "word": "there",
        "sentence": {
            "word_one": "i",
            "word_two": "dream",
            "word_three": "about",
            "word_four": "cheese"
        }
    }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
            .onAppear(perform: decode)
    }
    
    func decode() {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        do {
            let result = try decoder.decode(Content.self, from: json)
            print(result)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

// MARK: - ContentElement
struct ContentElement: Codable {
    let number: Int
    let word: String
    let sentence: Sentence
}

// MARK: - Sentence
struct Sentence: Codable {
    let wordOne, wordTwo, wordThree, wordFour: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case wordOne = "word_one"
        case wordTwo = "word_two"
        case wordThree = "word_three"
        case wordFour = "word_four"
    }
}

typealias Content = [ContentElement]
```

I use a program called [quicktype](https://quicktype.io) and it prepopulates the structs you'll need to decode JSON. I apologize I can't explain further because I too don't know.